# Regex Replace function: in cases of no match, $1 returns full line instead of null

Tags: regex, regex-group, regexp-replace

Test link: [regexr.com/42d9c](http://regexr.com/42d9c)

This has been driving me crazy.

I want to extract barcodes in the lines below:

```
Ceres Juice Apricot 12 x 1lt unit: 6001240102022
Ceres Juice Cranberry& Kiwi Juice 12 x 1lt... unit:
Ceres Juice Guava 12 x 1lt.. unit:6001240222829
Ceres Juice Orange 12x1lt... unit:
Ceres Juice Medley of Fruits 1L x 12 unit: 6001240100660
```

It should return:

```
6001240102022

6001240222829

6001240100660
```

I correctly use `.*(\d{13}).*`

And then I use `$1` for it to return the first match

But my results look like this:

```
6001240102022
Ceres Juice Cranberry& Kiwi Juice 12 x 1lt... unit:
6001240222829
Ceres Juice Orange 12x1lt... unit:
6001240100660
```

**Cause:**

The cause of this problem is that 'Replace' returns the original string if there is nothing in the match group ($1).

**Workaround:**

Ensure that there is a 'match' on every single line, and put this into Match Group 1 ($1). Then put your actual match into Match Group 2 ($2). How to do this?

**Language/Platform:**

Any. I have tried all online Regex websites and also Notepad++

Comment: Add an alternative that matches any string, `.*(\d{13}).*|.*`. Or, use `(?:.*(\d{13}))?.*`

Comment: A quick test shows this works:`.*(\d{13}).*|.*` Not sure how yet >.< But thank you! I have been grappling with this for about 3 hours

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may add an alternative that matches any string,

```
.*(\d{13}).*|.*
```

The point is that the first alternative is tried first, and if there are 13 consecutive digits on a line, the alternative will "win" and `.*` won't trigger. `$1` will hold the 13 digits then. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/32y4RP/2).

Alternatively, an optional non-capturing group with the obligatory digit capturing group:

```
(?:.*(\d{13}))?.*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/32y4RP/1)

Here, `(?:.*(\d{13}))?` will be executed at least once (as `?` is a greedy quantifier matching 1 or 0 times) and will find 13 digits and place them into Group 1 after any 0+ chars other than linebreak chars. The `.*` at the end of the pattern will match the rest of the line.

Comment: Many thanks Wiktor.
You have put me out of my misery :) 
And I have learnt some useful stuff here.
However, I'm wondering if your terminology is 100% because I think technically your solution is causing **matches** (not just groups!) for every line, whereas my solution was not: my solution failed to even 'match' on certain lines. You also speak of a 'Group 2' when there is not any. Nonetheless I am very happy and grateful for your help. Thank you!

Comment: @RichardWoolf Sure, there is only Group 1, I fixed that part in my explanation. Matches, yes, but there is one capturing group here and I use the verb to "capture"  when a pattern wrapped in a pair of unescaped parentheses matches some part of a string.

Comment: Also, thank you for demonstrating a capturing-group inside a non-capturing group; when I tried this before your help, I thought it was not possible – I thought the non-capturing part was superior to / had authority over the inner-group.