# Regex replace: return empty none/empty string if no match

Tags: python, regex, substitution

So i thought i know a bit of regex but it seems i found a case where my knowledge is at is end.
Anyway i tried the following [Regex Replace function: in cases of no match, $1 returns full line instead of null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53119343/regex-replace-function-in-cases-of-no-match-1-returns-full-line-instead-of-nu)
But the main difference is i want to not only replace the input with the match but also insert some characters inbetween the matches. Simply put i want to standardize the input to a certain pattern.
The regex i want to match and capture specific parts of the input but not everything

```
^[\D]*(?P<from_day>(0?[1-9])|([12][0-9])|3[01])[\.\-\s,■]+(?P<from_month>(0?[1-9])|(1[0-2]))[\.\-\s,■]*(?P<until_day>(0?[1-9])|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\.\-\s,■]+(?P<until_month>(0?[1-9])|1[012])[\D]*$
```

the replacement string:

```
\g<from_day>.\g<from_month>-\g<until_day>.\g<until_month>
```

Input:

```
28.11 16.12
"13.01 23,09"
01.08.-31.12
"01.01,-51.12"
"01,01.-31,12."
01083112
1.02 - 4.3
```

Current output:

```
28.11-16.12.-.
13.01-23.09.-.
01.08-31.12.-.
.-..-.
01.01-31.12.-.
.-..-.
1.02-4.3.-.
```

Expected/desired:

```
28.11-16.12
13.01-23.09
01.08-31.12

01.01-31.12

1.02-4.3
```

https://regex101.com/r/M3arvW/1

Comment: This question is tagged python, so please show us the python code.

Comment: So basically the regex is inside a yaml and gets loaded and handed to a the call function of a class:
new_text = re.sub(self.regex, self.replacement, self.text)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the relevant code. It's always best to provide a [mre]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change your regex to this:

```bash
^\D*(?P<from_day>[12]\d|3[01]|0?[1-9])[.\s,■-]+(?P<from_month>1[0-2]|0?[1-9])[.\s,■-]*(?P<until_day>[12]\d|3[01]|0?[1-9])[.\s,■-]+(?P<until_month>1[012]|0?[1-9]).*|.+
```

[Updated RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/M3arvW/3)

This will take care of all the issues except when there is no match. For no match you should use a `lambda` function `re.sub` to replace with an empty string.

**Python Code:**

```bash
>>> import re
>>> arr = ['"01,01.-31,12."', '01083112', '1.02 - 4.3', '"01.01,-51.12"']
>>> rx = re.compile(r'^\D*(?P<from_day>[12]\d|3[01]|0?[1-9])[.\s,■-]+(?P<from_month>1[0-2]|0?[1-9])[.\s,■-]*(?P<until_day>[12]\d|3[01]|0?[1-9])[.\s,■-]+(?P<until_month>1[012]|0?[1-9]).*|.+')
>>> for i in arr: print (rx.sub(lambda m: m.group('from_day') + '.' + m.group('from_month') + '-' + m.group('until_day') + '.' + m.group('until_month') if m.group('from_day') else '', i))
...
01.01-31.12

1.02-4.3
```